# react native: style props on TouchableOpacity component

Tags: react-native

In react native docs(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity), there is no explanation about style props. But I already know using style props on TouchableOpacity component is okay.

for example

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get you but TouchableOpacity can set props "activeOpacity" for changing the opacity when clicking to the button.

Comment: I add more explanation Can you give me any help?

Comment: You can style TouchableOpacity by using the opacity: <TouchableOpacity style={{opacity: '0.5', fontSize:'20'}}> and it only accept the Opacity, not the fontSize, just like the props activeOpacity.